# Warning: React does not recognize the X prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am getting this error when I am just trying to pass props around. Very basic stuff.

```js
interface Props extends Omit<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, 'color'>, ChakraProps {
  handleMoveAll: () => void
}

export const MyWrapper: FC<Props> = (props): JSX.Element => (
  <div {...props}>
    <IconBox label="Move All" onClick={props.handleMoveAll}>
      <MyIcon />
    </IconBox>
  </div>
)
```

And then I call the component `MyWrapper` on its parent where the warning is coming from.

```js
export const ParentComp: FC<{}> = (): JSX.Element => {
  const myFunction = () => console.log('Hit it')

  return (
      <MyWrapper handleMoveAll={() => myFunction()}>
         <p>Child Component</p>
      </MyWrapper>
  )
}
```

> Warning: React does not recognize the `handleMoveAll` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `handlemoveall` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

If I remove this `handleMoveAll={() => myFunction()}` the warning is gone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is `<div {...props}>` in `MyWrapper`; that adds the `handleMoveAll` prop onto the div. What you could do is something like:

```
export const MyWrapper: FC<Props> = (props): JSX.Element => (
  const {handleMoveAll, ...rest} = props;
  <div {...rest}>
    <IconBox label="Move All" onClick={handleMoveAll}>
      <MyIcon />
    </IconBox>
  </div>
)
```

to pull out `handleMoveAll` from the passed-in props, while still passing any other props into the div.

Comment: Why an array and not `const { handleMoveAll, ...rest } = props` ?

Comment: @Reacting Because I was typing more quickly than I was thinking. :P Editing.

Answer (score 3):

`<div {...props}` - this is why you are getting a warning.

`handleMoveAll` is not a valid attribute for a `div` element. React generates this warning for multiple reasons and one of them is when you try to add a non-standard DOM attribute on a native DOM element.

From [React Docs - Unknown Prop Warning:](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html)

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM
> element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM
> attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not
> have spurious props floating around.

#### Solution

To fix this warning, don't add `handleMoveAll` attribute on the `div` element.

```
const MyWrapper: FC<Props> = ({ handleMoveAll, ...restProps }): JSX.Element => (
  <div {...restProps}>
    <IconBox label="Move All" onClick={handleMoveAll}>
      ...
    ...
  ...
)
```